# Output control in Bitmap

Tags: winforms, c#-2.0

I want to implement previews/thumbnails in my project, therefor i need the graphical output of a control as bitmap. I have a third party control which loads documents and displays them. Is it possible to fetch the output of an control and store it in a bitmap object without adding it to the UI? And If how?

**Edit:** I probably should said that before, but i don't know if that's important. The ThirdParty Control is an OCX(ActiveX control).

Comment: How a control can display documents(or whatever) if it is not part of any form? Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: you asked if "it possible to fetch the output", but what kind of output, if the control itself is not displayed, nor loaded to a form... I am not sure if is possible.

Comment: hmm... What a pity... then i probably have to find a workaround based on your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a Form do:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(button1.Width, button1.Height);

// button1.Draw..., not 'this.Draw...'!
button1.DrawToBitmap(myBitmap, button1.DisplayRectangle); 

myBitmap.Save(@"C:\test.bmp");
```

Comment: He said _without adding it to the UI?_

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, But it doesn't work as expected. I tried it with a button and i get Bitmap(size of the button) which shows the upper left conrner of the form(icon + titletext).

Comment: try once again avec le code MiseàJour. Finally, you can do it with any control using the Control.DrawToBitmap property. If your control is a AcX control, it may not have this method...

Comment: I have tested this code on a button and it works. Take attention that DrawToBitmap is called by the **button**, not by the **form**, paste your code if it not works.

Comment: If i replace the button with the OCX i get an InvalidActiveXStateException, which disappears if i add the OCX to the form. But then the Bitmap only contains a horizontal and vertical scrollbar. Maybe this doesn't work with OCX controls.